# track div class and data-id="" in javascript (jquery) as an example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

there is an example

```
<button id="tri" style='display: block;'>add</button>
        <div id="box" style='display: none;' >
```

tracked by `id`

```
$('#tri').on('click', function(){

                var e = document.getElementById('box');
                var b = document.getElementById('tri');
                if(e.style.display == 'none')
                    $("#box").slideDown();
                b.style.display = 'none';
            })
```

need to do the same so that this button tracks but only `class` and `data-id`

```
<div class="block_view" data-id="52" style='display: none; ></div>
```

what i tried did not work

```
<button class="editblock" data-id="51">edit</button>

<div class="block_edit" style="display: none;" data-id="51"></div>

<script>
        $('body').on('click', '.editblock', function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                id = $this.attr('data-id'); 
          var b = $('.block_view[data-id=id]');
           if(b.style.display == 'none')
            b.style.display = 'block';
        })
</script>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `id` contains dynamic data but you are using that as a string, you should form the selector in a proper way.

`b` refers to a jQuery element, you should use [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) instead of `style` property.

Try the following way:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.editblock', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
  id = $this.attr('data-id'); 
  var b = $('.block_view[data-id='+id+']');
  if(b.css('display') == 'none')
    b.css('display', 'block');
  else b.css('display', 'none');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="editblock" data-id="51">edit</button>

<div class="block_view" data-id="51" style='display: none;' >block_view</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you really helped !!
Hello from Ukraine!)

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the id variable in to selector, you are just putting the literal sting id in it. Also jQuery returns a jQuery object not an element, so you can use document.querySelector instead.

```
var b = document.querySelector('.block_view[data-id="'+id+'"]');
```

Comment: I did, but it gives an error, what can it be connected with? TypeError: b.style is undefined

Comment: I update SyntaxError: '.block_view[data-id=51]' is not a valid selector

Answer (score 0):

You can take `data-id` using `$(this).data('id');` and the style  by `$(this).css("display")`. you can find all `div` with the `data-id` and show/hide based on that

```js
$(".editblock").click(function() { 
  var id=$(this).data('id'); 
   console.log(id)
   var styles = $(this).css("display");
   console.log(styles)
     $("div").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id') == id  && $(this).css("display")=="none") {
            $(this).css('display','block');
        }
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button  class="editblock" data-id="51">edit</button>

 <div class="block_edit" >
 
 <div id="51" style="display:none">div1</div>
 <div id="52" style="display:none">div2</div>
 <div id="53" style="display:none">div3</div>
 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <button class="editblock" data-id="51">edit</button>
    <div class="block_edit" style="display: none;" data-id="51"></div>
    <div class="block_view" data-id="51" style='display: none;'>Demo</div>

</body>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('.editblock').click(function(){

          var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); 
          var b = $('.block_view[data-id='+id+']');
                if($(b).css('display')=='none'){
                    $(b).css('display','block')
                }
          });

</script>
</html>
```